# auto_ptr released without assigning its return value

Tags: c++, pointers

So what happens to a pointer if you release an object owned by auto_ptr but do not actually assign it to a raw pointer? It seems like it's supposed to be deleted but it never gets the chance to. So does it get leaked out "into the wild"?

```
void usingPointer(int* p); 

std::auto_ptr<int> point(new int);
*point = 3;

usingPointer(point.release());
```

Note: I don't use auto_ptr anymore, I use tr1::shared_ptr now. This situation just got me curious.

Comment: Change *"So does it get leaked out "into the wild"?"* to *"So does it get **released** "into the wild"?"* and you'll have your answer, and the inspiration behind the name. :) Yes, `release`'ing relieves the `auto_ptr` of all management duties.

Comment: `usingPointer` *could* delete it in this example. However, when you want a plain pointer while still letting the smart pointer manage the object, you'd use `point.get()` (also with `shared_ptr`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`release` isn't suppose to delete the owned point, from the docs:

> Sets the auto_ptr internal pointer to null pointer (which indicates it points to no object) **without destructing** the object currently pointed by the auto_ptr.

Also, it's overkill to replace all uses of your `auto_ptr` with `tr1::shared_ptr` - you should be using [`unique_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/unique_ptr.html) where a shared one isn't necessary.

Comment: I mostly replaced it when I realized auto_ptr doesn't apply a const copy constructor, and I would need the pointer to be copied and used among different instances of a class.

Answer (score 3):

Unless `usingPointer` is calling `delete` on `p`, this is a memory leak. If you would call `get` instead of `release` then the memory will be automatically deleted when `point` falls out of scope.